# Problema con ingreso de fechas al automatizar con python biblioteca paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, putty

Tengo un problema imposible de resolver. Necesito ingresar dos fechas en SSH. La idea es ingresar la primera fecha (20171101), luego presionar la tecla 'tab' y luego ingresar la segunda fecha (20171113). La siguiente instrucción es presionar 'enter'."

[image: Ingresando el dato de fecha]
[image: Resultado Final]

Les dejo el código:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy
import time

def wait_for_message(channel, success_message, error_message):
    output = ""
    while True:
        if channel.recv_ready():
            output += channel.recv(1024).decode()
            output = output.strip()  # Eliminar espacios en blanco adicionales
            print(output)
            if success_message in output:
                print(f"¡Mensaje: {success_message} encontrado! El programa ha finalizado.")
                return True
            elif error_message in output:
                print(f"¡Mensaje de error: {error_message} encontrado!")
                return False
            elif "Comando ejecutado" in output:
                # Ignorar líneas que contienen el mensaje "Comando ejecutado"
                output = ""
        time.sleep(5)

# Configuración de la conexión SSH
host = "192.168.xx.xxx"
port = 22
username = 'oracle'
password = 'oracle'

# Crear una instancia de cliente SSH
client = SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())

# Conectar al servidor remoto
client.connect(host, port, username, password)

# Abrir un canal SSH
channel = client.invoke_shell()

# Enviar los comandos uno por uno
commands = [
    'cd ..',
    'cd ..',
    'cd app',
    'cd oracle/',
    'cd admin/',
    'cd domains/',
    'cd wlsIC/',
    'cd ARX',
    'cd Shell',
    ' ./shell',
    'ABCDINxx',
    'Poxxstax',
    'y',
    'y',
    '3',
    'charge_rej_report',
    's',
    '20171101',
    '20171113',
    '',  # Opción para generar el informe

]

# Tiempo de espera relativo (ajustar según la velocidad de conexión y del equipo)
wait_time = 5

# Ejecutar los comandos iniciales
for command in commands:
    # Leer y mostrar la salida en tiempo real antes de enviar el comando
    while channel.recv_ready():
        output = channel.recv(1024).decode()
        if output:
            output = output.strip()  # Eliminar espacios en blanco adicionales
            print(output)

    # Esperar un tiempo antes de enviar el siguiente comando
    time.sleep(wait_time)

    # Enviar el comando
    channel.send(command + "\n")

    # Esperar un tiempo después de enviar el comando
    time.sleep(wait_time)

# Esperar el mensaje de éxito o error
wait_for_message(channel, "SUCCESSFUL RUN!..Press any key to continue...", "Invalid/Unauthorized Program.")

# Cerrar la conexión SSH
channel.close()
client.close()
```

El codigo me parece correcto sin embargo en la automatizacion no veo el resultado, el codigo termina una vez ingresado correctamente y a la espera del mensaje ""SUCCESSFUL RUN!..Press any key to continue..."

Pero en el log, el programa queda ejecutandose sin la respuesta requerida, y como se puede apreciar en la siguiente imagen, no llega al ingreso de la fecha...

[image: Log in Pycharm]

Nesecito ayuda, he intentado de todo.

Comment: Es posible que el `wait_for_message` se dé después de que ya se escribió la salida. No recuerdo si Paramiko tenía problema con eso o lo captura desde el buffer, pero podrías intentar quitando el `time.sleep()` al final del `for`. Si lo precisas ponelo al principio del loop.

Comment: NO, le borré el sleep wait y persiste.